# Cancel a Job that runs a coroutine and reuse the job object

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I currently have a job that executes some process (it is a bit cpu intensive takes about 10 seconds)

But I would like to cancel it immediately when the next call to executeProcess() comes.

```
private var myJob: Job? = null

fun executeProcess() {
    myJob?.cancel()
    myJob = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //doCPUIntensiveTask()
        //This is always Active!
        println("isActive $isActive ")
    }
}
```

How is this possible if I want to reuse the same job object? if not possible, Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: What do you mean by reuse job object? `launch` spawns a new job and you replace it with new one, you're doing it correctly so what's your issue exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve.
Btw you shouldn't run CPU intensive tasks on Dispatchers.IO, better use Dispatchers.Main for that.

Comment: @xap4o I think you mixed something up, Dispatchers.Main is ran on UI thread so IO or Default is correct

Answer (score 1):

- Cannot reuse because it has life-cycle [Job docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/)
- You can use `Flow` + `flatMapLatest` for same purpose [Flow docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html), [flatMapLatest docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html)